# How to fix Boot layer in initialization in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using selenium webdriver tool for automation testing. In this, I am facing an error whenever I import the `safariwebdriver` class and `Webdriver` method. The error sign not resolve.

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules
>   selenium.server.standalone and okio export package
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari to module net.bytebuddy

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Kindly insert external jar of selenium from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/selenium-java/selenium-java.jar.zip), as its not detected by eclipse as shown in screenshot

OR

If those jars are already present,
This happens when you have added the external jars in the ModulePath.

**Solution:**

1. Remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath".
2. Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars.
3. Review that all the jars are under the node "Classpath".